# Where's the Win32 resource for the mouse cursor for dragging splitters?

Tags: c++, winapi, native

I am building a custom win32 control/widget and would like to change the cursor to a horizontal "splitter" symbol when hovering over a particular vertical line in the control. IE: I want to drag this vertical line (splitter bar) left and right (WEST and EAST).

Of the the system cursors (OCR_*), the only cursor that makes sense is the OCR_SIZEWE. Unfortunately, that is the big, awkward cursor the system uses when resizing a window. Instead, I am looking for the cursor that is about 20 pixels tall and around 3 or 4 pixel wide with two small arrows pointing left and right.

I can easily draw this and include it as a resource in my application but the cursor itself is so prevalent that I wanted to be sure it wasn't missing something.

For example: when you use the COM drag and drop mechanism (CLSID_DragDropHelper, IDropTarget, etc) you implicitly have access to the "drag" icon (little box under the pointer). I didn't see an explicit OCR_* constant for this guy ... so likewise, if I can't find this splitter cursor outright, I am wondering if it is part of a COM object or something else in the win32 lib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are all sorts of icons, cursors, and images in use throughout the Windows UI which are not publicly available to 3rd-party software. Of course, you could still load up the module in which they reside and use them, but there's really no guarantee your program will keep working after a system update / upgrade.

Include your own. The last thing you want is adding an extra dependency over a tiny little cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.  When I looked back over some old code for a vertical splitter thinking I had an easy answer, it turned out that I had build and loaded my own resource:

```
SetCursor( LoadCursor( ghInstance, "IDC_SPLITVERT" ));
```

I vaguely remember investing some considerable time and effort into find the system way of doing it, so (my guess) is that there is not a system ICON readily available to do the job, so you are better off rolling your own.

This is one of those times when I would like to be wrong, as I would have liked there to be a system icon for this job.